Too Many Redirects Issue with Nginx Reverse Proxy and WordPress VPS Setup
I am running multiple WordPress sites on separate VPS instances managed by Proxmox. I'm using an Nginx reverse proxy server to manage HTTPS and forward traffic to each VPS. This setup is intended to be replicated for other sites in the future, which is why I'm using a reverse proxy and a dedicated VPS per site.
Currently, when I access my site via the browser, I get a "Too Many Redirects" error. The site works perfectly when accessed locally on the VPS over HTTP or using curl from the reverse proxy.
The firewall in my network is a Fortinet device, configured to forward all traffic on ports 80 and 443 to the reverse proxy vm. The reverse proxy is responsible for routing the traffic to the appropriate VPS. However, when I access my site via the browser, I get a "Too Many Redirects" error. The site works perfectly when accessed locally on the VPS over HTTP or using curl from the reverse proxy or just typing vps ip on local network.
Here's my current setup:
Infrastructure:

Hypervisor: Proxmox
Reverse Proxy Server: Nginx, acting as a gateway for multiple sites as vm.
VPS: Each site has its own VPS instance running Nginx and WordPress.

Reverse Proxy (Nginx) Configuration:
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.121;  # IP of the VPS
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    
            proxy_redirect http:// https://;
        }
    }

WordPress VPS (Nginx) Configuration:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    root /var/www/html/mysite.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /wp-config.php {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /xmlrpc.php {
        deny all;
    }
}

chatgpt also has suggested this on wp-config.php file (im not sure about if it works):
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');

Current Status:

Running curl -IL https://example.com from my machine shows a 200 OK.
The browser, however, displays a "Too Many Redirects" error.
WordPress is set to use https://example.com for both siteurl and home.
Logs show no obvious errors except for typical WordPress warnings about a plugin.

Additional Information:

The reverse proxy and the VPS are both on the same local network managed by Proxmox.
I've ensured that DNS records point to the reverse proxy's public IP.

Questions:
1 Is there an issue with my Nginx configurations for the reverse proxy or the WordPress VPS?
2 Could this be related to WordPress’s internal handling of HTTPS or permalinks?
3 Are there additional headers or configurations I should include to resolve this?
4 Is there a better approach to setting up Nginx reverse proxy with multiple WordPress sites on separate VPS instances managed by Proxmox?

If you are getting "Too Many Redirects", what is the specific URL that is causing the problem? You should be able to identify it by looking at the Nginx access log. Then you will have the correct URL to test using curl.

Thank you for your suggestion. Here is the result:
curl -ILv https://www.example.com
*Host example.com:443 was resolved.
*IPv4: myip
*Trying myip:443...
*Connected to example.com (myip):443
..checking certificates..
..setting some cookies..
<X-Redirect-By: WordPress
X-Redirect-By: WordPress
< Location: https://local-vps-ip/
Location: https://local-vps-ip/

Ignoring the response-body
Issue another request to this URL: 'https://local-vps-ip/'
Trying local-vps-ip:443...
connect to local-vps-ip port 443 from local-reverseproxy-ip port 45542 failed: Connection refused failed


You should use the "Edit" button to add relevant information to your question.

sorry im newbie...

The chatGPT code should solve your problem (you should only need to add the if{...}; the other stuff is just to let you know WHERE to put this in the file). Remember to flush your opcode cache if its not setup to auto-refresh.
